# How to continue try block when on exception with keyerror in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jython-2.7

```
    try:
        key1 = val1
        key2 = val2
        key3 = val3
    except KeyError:
        pass
    finally:
        createTask()
```

in the above example, that createTask() runs in loop and keys changes for every run, how to continue to key2 if there is KeyError at key1 for a particular run ?

Comment: You can't. You immediately exit the `try` and enter the `except` when an exception is raised.

Comment: is there any other way i could achieve this ?

Comment: Use three different `try ... except` blocks?

Comment: it has long list of keys

Comment: `if there is KeyError at key1` you present no operation that conceivably could trigger a `KeyError`. Please show the loop `createTask()`runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will do the job:

```py
for key, val in zip([k1, k2, k3], [v1, v2, v3]):
    try:
        key = val
    except KeyError:
        pass
    finally:
        createTask()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you simply pass on KeyError, you can use `dict` `get` to avoid triggering `KeyError`. Then you will simply have to make sure that `createTask()` is smart enough to detect this condition.

```
    key1 = your_dict.get(val1, None)
    key2 = your_dict.get(val2, None)
    key3 = your_dict.get(val3, None)
    createTask()
```